# Css só aplica em uma página, usando Spring MVC

Tags: java, css, aplicação-web, jpa, spring-mvc

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto usando Spring MVC  estou aplicando um css na pagina principal e está tudo certo.

```
<link href="${contextPath}resources/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
 <link href="${contextPath}resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
 <link href="${contextPath}resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

porém quando aplico o css em outrá pagina não funciona e estou usando o mesmo css descrito acima.
Será que alguém pode me ajudar.

Obs. Já fiz toda a configuração no arquivo de configuração do SpringMVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o `${contextPath}`, a melhor forma de se fazer com o Spring é utilizar um recurso do framework para mapear os recursos da aplicação.

Caso você esteja utilizando configuração via XML, seria desta forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 ...

 <!-- Mapeia os recursos abaixo da pasta resources para estarem disponíveis no path /resources/ -->
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 ...

</beans>
```

Ou utilizando `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

    }

    ...
}
```

E na sua página você utilizaria apenas:

```
<link href="/resources/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```